# Running Tasks Before Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net, web-services

We have a timer process (a JQuery plugin) that redirects after X number of minutes to the login page, all via JavaScript.  When the timer hits zero, I want to run a task (could be anything; however, in this specific scenario, it's a web service call).

So the process does:

```
if (zeroedOut) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    //Run finish-up processes
  }, 0);

  window.location = "login.aspx";
}
```

The issue I'm having is the web service that runs with the finish-up processes is not being called.  The web service call happens, the redirect happens, I don't see any errors (I have try/catch statements around the setTimeout call), but no WS call.

Has anybody got this to successfully work?  What might I be missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, re-reading, I'm a little confused - how are you (when as well) making the call to a web service - is it within the `//Run ...` comment area?

Comment: Yes, //Run finish-up processes is where the ws call happens, in an abstract form.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the actual web service call. If you could post that code and the .net framework web service method signature that it's calling, I might be able to help you troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why isn't your redirect in the `setTimeout` call? Otherwise, the redirect will happen before the queued code can run.

```
if (zeroedOut) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    //Run finish-up processes
    window.location = "login.aspx";
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: OK, I did change that, I did it that way, because I was afraid the task may block the login redirection, but that does make sense that I have to make any finishing tasks async... but I did that and still I am getting no WS call...  I think i know why, but still don't know what to do here.